# Выборка из двух столбцов таблицы

Tags: mysql, php, база-данных, sql

Как сделать, чтобы при поиске в результате выборки присутствовали только два столбца из таблицы, например, 'name' и 'lastname' ? У меня стоит вот так:

```
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'members' WHERE 'lastname' LIKE '%{$user_get}%' ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `lastname` FROM `members` WHERE `lastname` LIKE '%{$user_get}%' ");
```

Внимание на косые кавычки.